# PHP Curl login into APSX page, after need to post data to Login page

Tags: php, asp.net, post, curl

To start, I am sorry about my english, I am not good writing in English and I got no time to pass through the check spelling. kkk

So, here is the overview of my problem.
I was able to login into an ASPX page with PHP CURL command, sending the post data with all that crazing variables that ASPX request.
My problem is, to send the post data (with user and password) to the Login Page, I must after, send a post data (with some crazy stuff) to the Login Page, to gain access to the page, in other words, I only have access to the Login Page if I send some specify post data (with that crazy stuuf) to page, if I dont send it, I am redirect to the Main Page, not the Login Page.

I was able to do the CURL command to Login Page with the crazy post and get access to the Login Page.
Now, how do I send the Post with the user/password to the Login Page, after send the first crazy post to gain access to Login Page?

Did you guys undestood?
If not, I can try to explain more.

Thanks!!

Rafael

Comment: You simply do another curl request with same curl resource, but different post data. If you want some code - post what you have by now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the user access to pages that only available after login - you must save COOKIE from login page, and then send them every request. This can be done through the curl.

**Get cookie:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$header = substr($data, 0, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
$body = substr($data, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
preg_match_all("/Set-Cookie: (.*?)=(.*?);/i", $header, $res);
$cookie = '';
foreach ($res[1] as $key => $value) {
   $cookie .= $value . '=' . $res[2][$key] . '; ';
};
curl_close($ch);
```

**Return cookie to another curl request:**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
```